why is this program skipping the the scanf in this program
anytime i run this function in my program
void treeInput(){
    char temp;
    int x, tempRow, tempColm;
    while(x=0){
        scanf(" %c ", &temp);
        if(temp == 'Q'){
            x=1;
        } else if(temp == 'A'){
            for(int i = 0; i<TEMP; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j<TEMP; j++){
                    forest[i][j] = 'T';
                }
            }
        } else if (temp == 'T'||'E'){
            scanf("%d", &tempRow);
            scanf("%d", &tempColm);
            forest[tempRow][tempColm] = temp;
        }
    }
}

it skips the scanf making the rest of the function null and void and idk how to make it work
i tried to add a space before the %c in the scanf but that didn't work, it still skips it

Please see What is the effect of trailing white space in a scanf() format string? So scanf(" %c ", &temp); should be scanf(" %c", &temp); And you should check that every call to scanf() succeeds, for example if(scanf("%d", &tempColm) != 1) { /* handle error */ }

Sarah Madden, Save time, enable all compiler warnings.

You used an assignment (=) where you meant to use a comparison (==).
while(x=0) ...

should be
while(x==0) ...

But now we're checking x before giving it a value.
int x;

should be
int x = 0;


temp == 'T'||'E'

is equivalent to
temp == ('T'||'E')

When the left-hand size of || is a non-zero number as is the case here, it evaluates to 1. So the above is equivalent to
temp == 1

You want
temp == 'T' || temp == 'E'


No. The problem is while(x=0).

@Weijun Zhou No, what I said is definitely a problem. But so is yours. I'll add the one you brought up to my answer. Thanks

@WeatherVane while(x=0) will skip everything, "making the rest of the function null and void".

@WeijunZhou true, yes.

Don't post real answers when the problem is just a typo like this. Post a comment and vote to close.

@Barmar there are at least 4 faults in the code.

thank you for your answer, its working now

@Barmar, wut. _
